# Bind a CodeBehind instance of StackPanel to XAML

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, binding

I have an odd scenario.

I need to create a StackPanel in codebehind.  I then need to have that stackpanel bound to the UI in xaml.

Normally I would just use a ContentControl for this.  But it has focus issues (it cannot blocked from the tab order Focusable="False" has no effect).   I also tried a usercontrol, but that had the same issues.

So I need to use some other kind of control.  I have decided on a Panel.  (StackPanel seems as good as any of the panels.)

However, I can't seem to find a way to bind to my "In Code" stack panel in my Xaml?

**Is there a way to do this?  (WITHOUT using a contentcontrol or usercontrol)**

Comment: Why would you do any of that?

Comment: @H.B. Are you merely curious?  Or do you need more info to help me solve my issue?  If just curious: I am bridging the gap between AvalonDock's MVVM implementation and Prism.  If you need more info to help me solve this, then please be more specific in your question.

Comment: I just usually question any code-behind shenanigans because people love to shoot themselves in the foot for no apparent reason. As i do not know the specifics of your problem i cannot comment on whether this is a good idea to begin with...

Answer (score 1):

> it cannot blocked from the tab order Focusable="False" has no effect

What about [`IsTabStop`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.control.istabstop.aspx)?

Also the most lightweight thing to use is a [`ContentPresenter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.contentpresenter.aspx) which is what i would use.

Comment: IsTabStop causes all the items in the content control to not be in the tabstops too.

Comment: @Vaccano: Well, i have never seen any control which isn't an input control being a tab-stop anyway.

Comment: I am injecting a Prism Region into it.  So it has a lot of input controls inside.

Comment: @Vaccano: The point was that you should not need to change that property anyway because the container usually is not a tab-stop (at least the `ContentPresenter` as far as i can tell does not behave like that)

Comment: Yeah, I think you are right.  It is still focusable, but it is not int he tabstop.  That was my mistake.  Sorry for the mixup.

Comment: @Vaccano: Now i am confused, what is your problem? Have you tried a `ContentPresenter`? You wrote `it cannot blocked from the tab order`, and the `ContentPresenter` (itself) is not in the tab order.

Comment: Sorry for the mixup.  My issue is the focus-ability of it.  I tried a content presenter and it also would allow the focus, even if I set Focusable="false".  But I tried a panel in there too (just using some ad hoc code) and it happens with that as well.  This may be an issue with Avalon Dock.  I apologize for the poor question.

Answer (score 0):

Tested this in KAXAML, and the focus doesn't go to any of the items defined in the ContentPresenter or ContentControl when TAB is pressed.

```
<Page
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
  <StackPanel>
  <TextBox>aaaaa</TextBox>
  <TextBox>bbbbb</TextBox>
    <ContentControl Focusable="False">
    <ContentControl.ContentTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
    <StackPanel Focusable="False" Background="Red" Width="100" Height="50"></StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
    </ContentControl.ContentTemplate>
    </ContentControl>
    <ContentControl Focusable="False">
    <ContentControl.ContentTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
    <TextBox Focusable="False">hello</TextBox>
    </DataTemplate>
    </ContentControl.ContentTemplate>
    </ContentControl>
    <ContentPresenter Focusable="False">
    <ContentPresenter.Content>
    <TextBox Focusable="False">hello</TextBox>
    </ContentPresenter.Content>
    </ContentPresenter>
  <TextBox>ccccc</TextBox>
  <TextBox>ddddd</TextBox>
  </StackPanel>
</Page>
```

Comment: Odd.  Well in my app it is.  Here are several other posts that have the same issue:  http://forums.silverlight.net/p/183027/420261.aspx  http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/ae32d24e-ecc5-4e94-87d8-f3da2ff91ae0/